# How to customize Arshaw's jquery event calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

In my current project, client's requirement is to use some event calendar, I looked at the Adam Arshaw's Jquery based event calendar, it is so nice and having more than 50% features which my client need. But I will have to customize the event calendar. In the calendar, the month and week views are fully resembling my requirements but I need to customize the day view. I know, I'll have to debug the full code of the calendar. But can anyone help me the better way to do this? may be some of you have done it already. so if you could tell me the best practices to customize the calendar and also tell me the things which should be kept in mind will be very much helpful.

EDIT:I want to change the simple javascript "Prompt" to the jquery lightbox, I've already done it but I think doing that will cause memory leeks. because in the case of "prompt" the execution of the remaining code stopped but using lightbox instead, doesn't stop the remaining code to execute, for this I call the remaining code on my button's click event.

I removed that "prompt" and used lightbox in place of that and made all the variables like "title", "start", "end" and "allDay" to null in the "select" function.

Pls tell me, have I done right thing? or there is some better way to remove "prompt" and using our custom lightbox for user input?

Thanks

Comment: We'll be able to help you more if you come up with specific things you'd like to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the callbacks on the click and such to call your functions instead of the built-in ones.